# Problems getting started with Dart and using Dart Editor

Tags: dart, dart-editor, dart-pub

I've been eying Dart for a while and want to give it a shot developing a new web-app at work.
Unfortunately both me and my coworker have run into several set-backs.

Firstly, none of the samples work out of the box. Opening a sample will immediately show this in the "Output" tab:

> --- 07-Nov-2013 16:50:02 Running pub get ... --- Pub get failed, [1] Resolving dependencies...Failed NSS_Init call.
>
> This is an unexpected error. Please run
>
> ```
> pub --trace 'get'
> ```
>
> and include the results in a bug report on http://dartbug.com/new.
>
> ** Warning: Application may fail to run since packages did not get installed.Try running pub get again. **

Attempting to launch any of the simpler samples (without Polymer) will fail with this message:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
    http://localhost:3030/solar/web/packages/browser/dart.js
```

Adding the `dart.js` file manually to the project and altering the path will correct the issue.
But anything that requires the use of the Pub package manager will fail with the message `Failed NSS_Init call.` as shown above.

Has anyone else experienced these problems when staring out with Dart? Any tips or suggestions?

---

EDIT:
I'm using Windows 8 and downloaded the 64bit Dart Editor archive.

---

EDIT 2:

This is the output from the `--trace` flag (which is run with `pub get --trace` and not `pub --trace 'get'` as shown in the error message above...):

```
> pub get --trace

Failed NSS_Init call.
---- Log transcript ----
FINE: Pub 0.8.10+3.r29803
IO  : Spawning cmd /c ver
IO  : Finished ver. Exit code 0.stdout:Microsoft Windows [Version 6.2.9200]Nothi
ng output on stderr.
SLVR: Solving dependencies:
    | - browser any from hosted (browser)
IO  : Get versions from https://pub.dartlang.org/api/packages/browser.
SLVR: BacktrackingSolver took 0:00:00.047007 seconds.
    | - Requested 1 version lists
    | - Looked up 0 cached version lists
    | - Requested 0 pubspecs
    | - Looked up 1 cached pubspecs
    |
MSG : Resolving dependencies...
FINE: Clean up system cache temp directory C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Roaming\Pub\
Cache\_temp.
ERR : Failed NSS_Init call.
---- End log transcript ----
```

Comment: have you run pub install first? Then update? Are you behind a firewall that is preventing pub from downloading resources from the internet? Try without a proxy/firewall

Comment: @PaulCollingwood, yes, I're tried all of those already. Same problem. Errors out with `Resolving dependencies...Failed NSS_Init call."

Comment: perhaps run pub trace and post the output here might shed some light.

Comment: @PaulCollingwood I've added the output of the trace to my question. I hadn't posted it originally since it didn't seem to add anything new...

Comment: Nothing jumps out @ me but perhaps it'll help someone else answer this.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time anyway :)

Comment: I know it's not an answer, nor probably much help, but I struggled for a long time developing Dart in windows. Switching to Linux (Mint) and things often "just work" instead of fighting windows to make them work, and it seems much faster in general. The output will still be the same :)

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm not a Windows user but I feel your pain.  I think it's very important that Dart Editor is rock solid on Windows for Dart 1.0.  You should bring these up to the Google team via the mailing list or https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to stem from the way non-ASCII characters in the install path are handled in a third-party library (NSS) used in the Dart SDK.

Check here for the bug report and updates on the issue:
http://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=15364